# Creating custom log based alerts in Google Cloud Stack driver

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have a running kubernetes cluster and I am using stackdriver alerts to notify me of any failures. Basically I want an alert whenever I see this in the logs `humanInterventionNeeded`.

So, I have configured the following `User defined Metric`

[image]

When I click on `Edit Metric`, I can see the logs  based on the filter.
However, when I click on `View in Metrics Explorer`, I don't see any data for it

[image]

Am I missing anything in the configuration? There is definitely data for that period.
Due to this I think I don't receive any alerts?

Comment: Have there been logs that match this filter since you created the custom metric?  Data will only be created in Stackdriver from logs that are made after the metric is created. There's more troubleshooting information in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/#troubleshooting)

Comment: In addition to the comment above, have you tried specifying 'k8s_container' in the resource filter in Metrics Explorer?